# Having the same timestamp value for all maven project modules

Tags: java, maven, timestamp

I have a pom parent where we declare all our variable like timestamp
and i have a maven project with 2 modules where i create artifact for each module. Look at this picture :
[image: my maven project]

The created artifacts haven't the same value of timestamp !!
 I need to set the same value of the timestamp in the version for all created artifact.

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue with jenkins pipeline
By passing the timestamp in maven command like this :

```
    //Get the timestamp
        def now = new Date()
        def timestamp = now.format("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss",TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT+2'))

       $ mvn clean install -Dcurrent.time=${timestamp}
```

and i just found this link :[build-helper-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/build-helper-maven-plugin/pull/32/files)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a custom property in the parent, who'se value is, say:

```
<myCustomProperty>${maven.build.timestamp}</myCustomProperty>
```

...and use this value in all of the children (as opposed to re-evaluating the build timestamp in each of your children).

Comment: i belief, that this is what he did. @Inforedaster you are building all modules separatly or u build from your parent pom?

Comment: Sorry, my understanding is that he did not. He's using `${maven.build.timestamp}` in each of the children, which is of course, different; the difference is that `myCustomProperty` won't get overwritten when a child-module build starts.

Comment: i build all modules from parent pom.xml project